# Basechart (Ng2-Charts) Canvas max width <= 16384px in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, canvas, html5-canvas, ng2-charts

I prepared this eg in stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-nlvlrr-mwudnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,tsconfig.json&preset=node . You can see in Fifrefox everything after the 16384th pixel is not being rendered, while in Chrome the chart is being rendered fully. Is this the limitation of Firefox? Isn't it possible to render more pixels in that browser? Because in canvas max size tables they usually write that firefox renders up to 32768px. Maybe I am doing smth wrong?

Chrome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxDfz.png)

Firefox:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qICNl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 16384 x 2 = 32768

If you type `devicePixelRatio` in your browser's console you'll probably find `2`. You are most likely on a high-res monitor.

*Chart.js*, that is used behind the hood of your *Ng2-Charts* library, does have a [`devicePixelRatio` option](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/device-pixel-ratio.html) available. Its default value is `window.devicePixelRatio` (dPR), so if you don't set it explicitly, the library will resize your canvas automatically to match this *dPR*. They do this because on such monitors to have crisp pixels, we need to set the canvas buffer to the actual size of the monitors pixels, and then scale the rendered canvas down using CSS.

If you really need to set the canvas to a bigger initial value, you can use this option to limit the dPR to one, e.g

```js
lineChartOptions: ChartOptions<'line'> = {
  devivePixelRatio: 1,
  responsive: true,
  ...
```

Or you can keep the default and simply check the tables you found about the canvas max size, but divide it by `window.devicePixelRatio`.

Comment: This helped me figure out why my 16000px ng2-charts canvas became 24000px on another display). 
I chose this answer as correct, but it doesn't really answer my question. Canvas can have maxWidth===32000px in Firefox, but for ng2-charts canvas, its maxWidth<=16348px (for devicePixelRatio: 1) and I don't know why.